# List project variables API doesn't show all GitLab project (repository) variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm trying to list all the variables defined in my GitLab repository (project) using the following API: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/variables`

But, I don't get all the variables. I can see more variables defined here: `https://gitlab.com/[GROUP-NAME]/[PROJECT-NAME]/-/settings/ci_cd`

I also checked the following API documentation but didn't find anything to figure out the reason: [GitLab > Project-level CI/CD variables API > List project variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#list-project-variables)

Why is this happening? Is there any bug in GitLab?

*Note: `[PROJECT-ID]`, `[GROUP-NAME]` and `[PROJECT-NAME]` are placeholders and will be replaced with the actual values.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out. It seems like the `list project variables` API doesn't show **more than 20** variables by **default**. I just made a wild guess of trying out passing a `page` variable with the API call and it worked. See this: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/variables?page=2`

On the second page, the remaining (missing) variables appeared which means that they do exist and are accessible.

These details regarding this pagination variable (`page`) are missing from the official documentation of [GitLab's APIs (list project variables)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#list-project-variables).

*Note: `[PROJECT-ID]` is a placeholder and will be replaced with the actual value.*

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set how many variables you want to be listed on the page with: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/variables?page=1&per_page=1000`